# Connect TortoiseSVN to Ubuntu repository

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, tortoisesvn

Our sysadmin created a SVN server on our Ubuntu server and I connect Eclipse to it using: svn+ssh://myuser@111.111.111.111/home/svn/myrepo/trunk but I now want to use Tortoise on my Windows7 machine to connect and I just cannot get it to work.

I right-click on an empty folder TortoiseSVN>Repo-browser and I am prompted to supply a URL. Before anybody recommends it, I did try svn+ssh://myuser@111.111.111.111/home/svn/myrepo/trunk but nothing! It says "Unable to open connection"

Can I even connect TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed all the SSH dependencies for Tortoise to use SVN over SSH? If not have a peek at the tortoise SVN [faq section on how to do it](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html) specifically the section entitled SSH Client Tools for use with TortoiseSVN.